# Incorrect Syntax near Keyword Group

Tags: sql

Hello I'm writing an sql query But i am getting a syntax error on the line with the GROUP BY. What can possibly be the problem.

```
SELECT au_lname, au_fname, t.title_id
from authors As a INNER JOIN
titleauthor As ta On a.au_id = ta.au_id INNER JOIN
titles As t On t.title_id = ta.title_id
ORDER BY au_lname, au_fname
GROUP BY au_lname
```

Comment: There is not much sense in applying a GROUP BY if you don't use an aggregate function as well. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Get rid of duplicate results in the resulting table

Comment: that's better done using DISTINCT

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Place GROUP BY before ORDER BY. Also, all fields included in the select must either be in the GROUP BY statement, or be inside an aggregate function.

Try this:

```
SELECT au_lname, au_fname, t.title_id
from authors As a INNER JOIN
titleauthor As ta On a.au_id = ta.au_id INNER JOIN
titles As t On t.title_id = ta.title_id
GROUP BY au_lname, au_fname, t.title_id
ORDER BY au_lname, au_fname
```

If you just want to get rid of duplicate results, you can also use keyword DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT au_lname, au_fname, t.title_id
from authors As a INNER JOIN
titleauthor As ta On a.au_id = ta.au_id INNER JOIN
titles As t On t.title_id = ta.title_id
ORDER BY au_lname, au_fname
```

Answer (score 0):

General syntax for select statement is

```
SELECT select_list
[INTO new_table_]
FROM table_source
[WHERE search_condition]
[GROUP BY group_by_expression]
[HAVING search_condition]
[ORDER BY order_expression [ASC | DESC] ;
```

so in your case

```
SELECT au_lname, au_fname, t.title_id
from authors As a INNER JOIN
titleauthor As ta On a.au_id = ta.au_id INNER JOIN
titles As t On t.title_id = ta.title_id
GROUP BY au_lname
ORDER BY au_lname, au_fname
```

Comment: This will not work. Select fields au_fname and t.title_id must either be placed in the group by, or aggregated with an aggregate function.